# How to read a whole column in Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will output the contents of a column inside a spreadsheet to a txt file.  I don't know powershell but I found and figured out how to get a cell, now I need the whole column.  The spreadsheet in question has 8K+ rows.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$SMTPApprovedXLS = "c:\temp\SMTP\SMTPAPPLIST.XLS"
$SheetName = "Active"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $False
$Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.open($SMTPApprovedXLS)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$startRow = 4

[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
    ApprovedIPs = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(4,$startRow).Value()
}
```

The column is "D" and should start at row 4.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is use a loop to run through all the entries and capture the data. Try this:

```
$SMTPApprovedXLS = "c:\temp\SMTP\SMTPAPPLIST.XLS"
$SheetName = "Active"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $False
$Workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.open($SMTPApprovedXLS)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$startRow = 4

$ApprovedIPs = @()

$count = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(65536,4).End(-4162)

for($startRow=4; $startRow -le $count.row; $startRow++)
{
 $ApprovedIPs += $Worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow, 4).Value()
}

$ApprovedIPs | Out-File C:\ApprovedIPs.txt
```

Note that the last line is what creates the txt file with the desired data, where `C:\` is the directory and `ApprovedIPs` is the file name. You can just substitute them for your desired location and name of the file.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you for the help!